# Netcat/nc messages not send/received on either computer

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, netcat

I have two computers (both running Ubuntu) in the same network. They are able to ping each other successfully. Their IPs are:

*Computer 1:* 172.16.10.59

*Computer 2:* 172.16.10.72

---

The following works: **Listening on Computer 1** on a random port (let's say 1234), and establishing a **connection from Computer 2 to Computer 1**. I can use netcat like a chat program then (as expected).

On computer 1:

```
$ nc -l 1234
```

On computer 2:

```
$ nc 172.16.10.59 1234
```

---

But vice-versa doesn't work: **Listening on Computer 2** on the same port (1234), and establishing a **connection from Computer 1 to Computer 2**.

On computer 2:

```
$ nc -l 1234
```

On computer 1:

```
$ nc 172.16.10.72 1234
```

All that happens is that netcat runs on both computers, but when I type in a message in either computer and hit enter, it isn't displayed on the other computer at all.

I'm quite lost in what could be wrong here, and I couldn't find a working solution online so far. Is anyone here able to help me? Thank you!

Comment: Firewall on Computer 2?

Comment: I already deactivated ufw and sudo ufw status returns "Status: inactive"

Comment: Could something else be running on port 1234 on the second computer? A suspended netcat process perhaps?

Comment: @anyone who comes across the same problem, Shubham Abrol's answer to this question worked for me https://askubuntu.com/questions/572848/network-manager-not-working